# Distribute selected images across multiple Google Slides using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

What would be a good way to turn a selection of images to individual slides? This would allow one to drop a folder/multiple images into one slide, select them, and with one fell swoop, distribute them to individual slides, which saves a lot of time compared to the alternative of making a new slide and dropping an image, one-by-one.

I'm thinking something like the following, need help fixing it so that it is not pseudo code

`const selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection(); var currentSlide; selection.forEach( currentSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().getObjectId(); presentation.insertSlide(currentSlide, BLANK) slide.insertImage(image) );`

delete the original selection, not sure what good practice code for that would be

alternative would be to iterate through the selection and move them one by one, but that seems an unnecessary replication of how a human would do it.

I've made another script that centers existing images on slides, but stuck about here

```
function sortImage() {
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  //store selected slide
  let selectedSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().asSlide();
  //gets all the images in the first slide
  let images = selectedSlide.getImages();
  // trying to get insertion index of selected slide
  let selectedSlideIndex = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().getObjectId();

  // iterates all images in the array
  images.forEach((image) => {
    //adds a new slide
    slide.insertSlide(selectedSlideIndex += 1)
    let current_slide = slide.getSlides()[selectedSlideIndex];

    //insert the image in the newly created slide
    current_slide.insertImage(image);

    //delete the image in the first slide. 
    image.remove()
  });
}
```

Comment: Are the files store in Google Drive (inside a folder in Google Drive)? Or are you pulling the images from a different location?

Comment: I can upload them to google drive, but in my original question I was drag and dropping them in a slide from the computer directly.

Comment: thanks for the update. I added an update to the answer base on that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test to upload images to Google Slides; you mentioned that you had a script that centers existing images, so I just added a sample of how to upload an image per slide.

The sample is taking images stored inside a Google Drive folder. You can modify this depending on where your store your images.

```
function uploadImage() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_ID).getFiles();
  let count = 0
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  while (folder.hasNext()) {
    slide.appendSlide()
    let current_slide = slide.getSlides()[count += 1];
    let file = folder.next();
    let file_id = file.getId();
    let image = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
    current_slide.insertImage(image);
  }
}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

Get all the images in the first slide. (For this example, you need to add the images in the first slide.)

```
function sortImage() {

  //gets all the images in the first slide
  let images = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getImages();
  let count = 0
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();

  // iterates all images in the array
  images.forEach((image) => {
    //adds a new slide
    slide.appendSlide()
    let current_slide = slide.getSlides()[count += 1];

    //insert the image in the newly created slide
    current_slide.insertImage(image);

    //delete the image in the first slide. 
    image.remove()
  });
}
```

[image]

**References to list the files inside a folder:**

- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles)
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)
- [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid)

**References to add slides and insert an image:**

- [appendSlide()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#appendslide)
- [insertImage(blobSource)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout#insertimageblobsource)
- [getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getslides)
- [getImages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getImages())
- [remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#remove())

**Update:**

To get the number of slides in a presentation, you can use:

```
let total_number_slides = slide.getSlides().length;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick q. If I didn't want to use google drive and drag and dropped images in a slide, how would I go about distributing them? Something like:

function imagesToSlides() {
  const selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  const elements = selection.getPageElementRange().getPageElements();
  let count = 0
  let image = elements[count];
  const slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  elements.forEach(function(value) {
  slide.appendSlide();
  let current_slide = slide.getSlides()[count += 1];
  current_slide.insertImage(image);
 });
}

Comment: Let me check and do some tests

Comment: @whatsnewsisyphus, I added an update with the information that you wanted.

Comment: The one shortcoming of the first slide method is that if you already have slides, it doesn't work (like adding to existing slides). Is there a way to get the index of a slide to use it as an insertion index rather than appending to the end?

Comment: I'll add it as an edit to the top in broken code.

Comment: Also, a minor fix that makes the code above work with existing slides (you just have to manually move the group of generated slides is below, so that it is inserting the new slides in the beginning, respecting existing sldes
    //adds a new slide
    slide.insertSlide(count += 1) 
    let current_slide = slide.getSlides()[count];

Comment: Yes, the `appendSlides()` part is the one that creates the slide at the end. I usually use that one to keep a better track of the slides with a simple count. It can be modify to use another method that adds the slides at the beginning as you mentioned. Basically the code can be modify depending of the situation. Just the same the most important part is the iteration in the images that will allow you to add just one image per slide.

Comment: If you already have slides in the presentation you can also modify the count to the same number of existing slides, that way it will start inserting the image in the new slide that will be created. Or you can use the method you mentioned to create the slide at the beginning, which ever is better for you.

Comment: Is there a way to count the total number of existing slides? I could automate the append method that way and leave fixed code above for future ref.

Comment: @whatsnewsisyphus,maybe using `let total_number_slides = slide.getSlides().length;` This should provide you with the total number of slides.